# How to ignore blank criteria in queries in Access

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, criteria

I'm currently working with an update query, that works as expected until I add in criteria that makes the query not display any results (which I expected). The criteria is currently coming from textboxes on a form.

What I want to be able to do is, in the criteria line, specify that if the the textbox is blank with nothing in it, then the criteria should just skip that.

I've tried in the Criteria line:

```
[Forms]![Formname].[txtboxName] OR [Forms]![Formname].[txtboxName] Is Null
```

but that doesnt work.

Thank you for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a wildcard:

```
Like [Forms]![Formname].[txtboxName] & "*"
```

Comment: Please start providing information. I am tired trying to guess.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
where [whatever your field is] = [Forms]![Formname].[txtboxName]
OR Nz([Forms]![Formname].[txtboxName]) = ""
```

The use of `Nz` will catch both null values and zero length strings, which look null but are not.

If that doesn't work, please do as Remou requested. I.E. Update your question with the actual SQL query instead of just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Like IIF(IsNull([Forms]![Formname].[txtboxName])=Fasle;[Forms]![Formname].[txtboxName];"*")
```

***Note**: my system default separator is ";", make sure what yours.
Enjoy the Ride